# Source Control Explorer hanging

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, source-control-explorer

I have an issue with Source Control Explorer. When it loads all it does is show "Working..."

[image]

I have tried:

```
Visual Studio 2017 Explorer
Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise (what I normally use)
Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 

Update 1: I cleared my TFS Cache completely with no luck.
Update 2: I uninstalled all Visual Studio Versions and installed the latest version of SQL Server 2022 Enterprise
```

How can this be resolved?

> Note: Bounty was inadvertanly put in to show needing authoritative
> answer. It just needs more exposure but I couldnt find a way to edit
> it.

Comment: Have you tried accessing TFS via a browser from that same machine?  Does it connect or throw an exception?